# Auto Format Input for Stopwatch time with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an input on my site allow for people to put their times in and want it to be a stopwatch-style format.

Here is what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/k4q3x0hd/3/

```
$('.time_score').keydown(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
        return value.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ":");
    });
});
```

What I need it to do is account for if someone puts in 60 (for seconds) it auto formats to 00:60:00.

What are some ways to format this to allow it auto add the 00 Before and after the 60 but still retain the ability for the user to input a full min:sec:mil time set.

I am new to regex and trying to figure out, forgive me if this is an easy fix.

Added for more details:

The users will enter event times for sports and the input would be in a 00:00:00 format (Min:Secs:Miliseconds). If the user completes an event in 60 seconds the score taker my just type 60 instead of 00:60:00, I would like to find a way to check entries so that if they put half it will correct it to adding the 00: in front or pop up a message that explains correct format

Comment: Try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), it'd helpful.

Comment: Can you be more explicit on what you are trying to achieve? What are some use cases?

Comment: @AndreiCioara Added more details

Comment: would 60 seconds not auto format to `01:00:00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use regular expressions, try this one: `^(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}$`. Technically you could also use `^(?:\d\d:){2}\d\d$`, which I guess is actually 2 characters shorter. Both accomplish the same thing: only "00:00:00" should end up matching that, so if you string *doesn't* then you can replace it with 00:{user value}:00.

Javascript has a quick way to test a string against a regex: `/regex/.test(string)`.

So fully:

```
var regex = /^(?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}$/;

$(".time_score").blur(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (!regex.test(value)) {
    $(this).val("00:" + value + ":00");
  }
});
```

Here's an updated working example: https://jsfiddle.net/k4q3x0hd/16/

From your code, I changed it to on blur just to keep this from firing every time someone enters something in (as yours did with keydown).